# Cannot Find Content in Samsung GT-N8000 (Note 10.1 Kitkat) Connected to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Dell)

Tags: 12.04, usb, android, samsung

I am a beginner-level Ubuntu user. My Samsung Note tablet (specs given in Title) connected without issues and showed as an external USB device on the dashbar at first. After a few days, and a lot of updates etc done on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, the following has happened:

1. Tablet connects and is identified as SAMSUNG_Android unlike GT-N8000 previously
2. Does not show up as an external USB on the dash. Rather shows up as a drive in home folder with option to mount/unmount
3. All the folders are visible but no contents inside. The top of the folder says - There are files loaded on an audio player (something similar to that) and Open VLC media player
4. The Tablet is running Android Kitkat and MTP is checked. USB debugging is unchecked. Checking/unchecking USB debugging mode had no effect.

I followed some of the advice available online. Following are the links for reference but not pasting content here.

1. http://hdfpga.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/connecting-samsung-samsung-galaxy-tab.html
2. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access

But on completion of their instructions which were more or less similar, the terminal started opening up with:

```
“alias: command not found
“alias: command not found
“alias: command not found
divyank@divyank-Inspiron-3542:~$
```

I realized I had made an error in copy pasting the android-connect and android-disconnect links before - did not re-type the quotes in the command given on the website.
I redid the whole procedure but fixing the quotes hasn't helped either. The tablet connection problem still the same.
The Terminal is now opening with these:

```
“alias: command not found
“alias: command not found
“alias: command not found
bash: alias: -o: not found
bash: alias: allow_other: not found
bash: alias: /media/SAMSUNG_Android: not found
bash: alias: -u: not found
bash: alias: /media/SAMSUNG_Android: not found
divyank@divyank-Inspiron-3542:~$
```

When I typed the command android-connect after connecting the tablet, this came up:

```
divyank@divyank-Inspiron-3542:~$ android-connect
fuse: missing mountpoint parameter
divyank@divyank-Inspiron-3542:~$
```

I do not have programming knowledge but detailed advice is most welcome.
Thank you all! :)